# Improve Regex for match valid values

Tags: javascript, regex, pcre

I need some help building this three RegEx since I'm missing something and some values are not matched.

- First [test here](http://regex101.com/r/xH3zW4/1)]:
      `^(?:(?:00|\+)58|0)(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789]))\d{7}$`

  Input (valid values pattern): 02121234567, +582121234567, 2121234567, (212)123.41.25, (212)-123.41.25
  Input (invalid values pattern): (9212)123.41.25, (21200)-123.41.25

  In this case the RegEx build I made works for this patterns: 02121234567, +582121234567 but not for the rest

  - Second [test here](http://regex101.com/r/kN5qS3/1)]:
    `^(?:(?:00|\+)58)(?:4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7}$`

  Input (valid values pattern): 04241234567, +584241234567, 4241234567, (424)123.41.25, 04141234567, +584141234567, 4141234567, (414)123.41.25, 04121234567, +584121234567, 4121234567, (412)123.41.25
  Input (invalid values pattern): (123)123.41.25, (4246)123.41.25

  In this case the RegEx build I made works for this patterns: +584241234567 but not for the rest

  - Third:
    `^\+?(?:\(\d{1,4}\)|\d{1,4})?\s*[\d\s.]{6,14}$`

  Input (valid values pattern): +584242511330, 00584242511330, 4242511330, (424)251.13.30
  Input (invalid values pattern): 123 456 213, +12 345 678, +48 315 182 12 63, (4567)8457435

  In this case the RegEx build I made works but allow also invalid patterns

Can I get some help here?

Comment: Can you provide more context about the type of info you are trying to match? it is terribly unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: This does require more detail in order to be actually helpful to you. For instance, what is the criterion to make in the first batch "(212)123.41.25" valid, but "(9212)123.41.25" invalid?

Comment: @QuantumLicht those are "kind" of valid phone numbers in Venezuela where area code is 3 integer (212) followed by phone number 1234125, I provided a set of matched strings, what is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start for the first one:

```
^(?:(?:(?:00|\+)58|0)?(?:2(?:12|4[0-9]|5[1-9]|6[0-9]|7[0-8]|8[1-35-8]|9[1-5]|3[45789]))\d{7})|(?:\(212\)-?\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$
```

[RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/xH3zW4/2)

… for the second one:

```
^(?:(?:(?:00|\+)58)(?:4(?:1[246]|2[46]))\d{7})|(?:0?\d{10})|(?:\(4(?:[12]4|12)\)\d{3}\.\d{2}\.\d{2})$
```

[RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/kN5qS3/2)

For the last one, more input is required, how to differentiate between valid and invalid values.
[RegEx101](http://regex101.com/r/tI9mW9/1)